# Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?) when converting csv from text

Tags: python

I tried to run this code:

```
txt_file = r"Fun.txt"
in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rb"), delimiter = '\t')
csv_file = r"NewProcessedDoc.csv"
with open(csv_file, 'w', newline ='') as csvfile:
    swriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
    swriter.writerow(in_txt)
print('done! Check NewProcessedDoc.csv file')
```

but have an error as:

```
swriter.writerow(in_txt)

Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

Could anyone please help?
Thank you!

Comment: did you noticed that you are opening you `in_txt` in `"rb"` which is binary mode?

Comment: As @MoinuddinQuadri said, your error is in the reading mode. Change it to `in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter = '\t')`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was in binary mode, by reading in normal mode I get the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the file in text mode: `...open(txt_file, "rb")`
- Use the `.writerows()` method not `.writerow()`: `swriter.writerows(in_txt)`

Comment: By changing to open(txt_file, "r") the problem was solved! Thank you